# Proving $(V/\ker T)\cong F$ if $T:V\to F$ is a non-zero homomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

$\newcommand{\Hom}{\text{Hom}}$
I want to prove the following

> If $T\in\Hom_{F}(V,F)$ is non-zero, then $(V/\ker T)\cong F$.

**My Attempt:**
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image: Commutative Diagram using First Isomorphism Theorem]

I wanted to show $\overline{T}$ in the above diagram, given by $\overline{T}(\overline{\alpha}):=T(\alpha)$, is an isomorphism. Here, $\Pi(\alpha):=\overline{\alpha}$.
I have been able to show $\overline{T}$ is injective. This is because if $\overline{\beta}\in\ker\overline{T}$, then since the above diagram is commutative, this implies $$\beta\in\ker T=\ker\Pi\implies\Pi(\beta)=0\implies\overline{\alpha}=\bar0.$$ So, $\overline{T}$ is injective. But I cannot show $\overline{T}$ is also surjective as that would require, by the First Isomorphism Theorem, that $\operatorname{Im}T=F$. So, how do I show that $\overline{T}$ is surjective ?

Comment: Hint: $\operatorname{im} \overline{T} = \operatorname{im} T$. What are the possible ranges of linear maps to the scalar field?

Comment: @TheoBendit : I'm not sure if I'm understanding your hint fully. Could you be bit more elaborate?

Comment: @Guillerminho77 : Can you think of a counter-example ?

Comment: @sadman-ncc The range of a linear map is a subspace of the codomain, which is dimension $1$. Thus, the only possible ranges are $\{0\}$ and $F$. The former case is ruled out, as $T \neq 0$ by assumption.

Comment: @TheoBendit : Yes, thank you. I totally forgot the fact that $\dim F =1$ in this case.

Comment: @Guillerminho77 A non zero linear functional is surjective. Isn't it?

Comment: I didn't know that $F$ was the scalar field of the spaces, i thought that it was an arbitrary space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T: V\to F$ linear map and $T\neq 0$ implies , $\exists k\neq 0\in R(T) $.

As $R(T) $ is non trivial subspace of $F$ and $\dim(F) =1$ . Hence $R(T) =F$

Now for any $k\in F, \exists v\in V$ such that $Tv=k$ .

Hence $\overline{T}(v+\ker(T)) =T(v) =k$

Hence $\overline{T}$ is surjective.

Comment: Why is $\dim F=1$???

Comment: @Desperado : $\dim_{F}F$ is always equal to $1$.

Comment: $F$is the scalar field.